# clusterboot function in the fpc package

Tags: r

I have a dataset of various measurements of eggs and coloration patterns etc.

I want to group these into clusters. I have used hierarchical clustering on the dataset, but I haven't found a good way to verify or validate the clusters.

I've heard discussion of cluster stability, and I want to use something like the clusterboot function in the fpc package. For some reason I can't get it to work though. I was wondering if there is anyone on here who has experience with this function.

Here is the code I was using below:

```
dMOFF.2007<-dist(MOFF.2007)
cf1<-clusterboot(MOFF.2007,B=3,bootmethod=boot,bscompare=TRUE,multipleboot=TRUE,clustermethod=hclust)
```

I'm just starting to understand what all of this means. I have experience with R but not with this specific function or much with cluster analyses.

I get this error:

```
Error in if (is.na(n) || n > 65536L) stop("size cannot be NA nor exceed 65536") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Any thoughts? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this because I'm working with clusterboot too--are you still stuck on this? I have two basic thoughts:  1) wouldn't you want to pass the distance matrix to clusterboot (dMOFF.2007) instead of the raw data (MOFF.2007)?  2)  for the clustermethod argument, I believe it should be hclustCBI, not hclust.  Hope you've got it working.